# Adding the ">" to a Process.Start instance

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How could I tell the program "test.exe" (which is a console application) to output its result to a file.

E.g. usually the program can output the data by doing test.exe > output.txt at the prompt.

How could this be done in this statement?

```
Process.Start("test.exe", "\"" + exename + "\"").WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You don't. The process writes to standard output, and the shell (or other caller) redirects standard output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

and if you only want to redirect the output to a file, called piping, you can ask cmd.exe to do that for you. i.e.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c test.exe \"" + exename + "\" > D:\\testOutput.txt").WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This. The ">" is interpreted by the command-line, not by your program, so instead of invoking your progeam directly you tell CMD.EXE to do it for you.

Comment: @KeithS Thanks for the clarification, that does make sense in my mind now :)

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) property as in this example from the MSDN page:

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
p.Start();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

As you can see you need to set the `RedirectStandardOutput` property of the `Process`'s `StartInfo`.

Comment: Cant you simply add the > output.txt operator to the existing process line?

Answer (score 0):

You can, in code, [redirect the standard output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) to a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx).