# Restore MySQL File via C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently working on a C# program. Part of the project involves piping in a SQL file into the MySQL Program to restore the file in to the database.

Below is my code that I am using.

```
command = string.Format("--host={0} --user={1} --password={2} --port={3} {4} < {5}",
                        MySQLConnectionManager.currentlyUsingConnection[MySQLConnectionManager.ConnectionKeyStrings.SERVER],
                        MySQLConnectionManager.currentlyUsingConnection[MySQLConnectionManager.ConnectionKeyStrings.USERNAME],
                        MySQLConnectionManager.currentlyUsingConnection[MySQLConnectionManager.ConnectionKeyStrings.PASSWORD],
                        MySQLConnectionManager.currentlyUsingConnection[MySQLConnectionManager.ConnectionKeyStrings.PORT],
                        db.database, restoreFile);
Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            //process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
            //string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string errorOutput = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

I don't get any errors though and if I redirect standard output I just get returned the contents of the file instead of actually performing the restore.

Comment: Invert [Adding the “>” to a Process.Start instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390925/adding-the-to-a-process-start-instance).

Answer (score 4):

In the shell, `<` pipes the contents of the given file into the standard input of the command.  However, since you set `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`, this means that the command won't be interpreted like a shell script, and all input/output redirection has to be done through the .NET interface.

### Option 1: Use the .NET interface

You'll need to write the contents of the file to `process.StandardInput`.  Unfortunately, `process.StandardInput` is a StreamWriter, and I know of no simple way to copy the contents of a file into a StreamWriter.  Perhaps using CopyToAsync on a FileStream of your file and sending it to StandardInput.BaseStream may work.

### Option 2: Use the Shell interface

Right now, you need to have `UseShellExecute = false` in order for `RedirectStandardError = true` to take effect.  The alternative is to redirect StdErr to StdOut in the command line, and set `UseShellExecute = false`.  You can do this by changing your format string to be:

```
"--host={0} --user={1} --password={2} --port={3} {4} < {5} 2>&1"
```

This may have other side effects, however, such as requiring a username to run as.

*Disclaimer: I have not actually tested either of these solutions.  They may or may not work.*

Answer (score 1):

A am more a linux programmer, But From my point of view, you are piping a filename to mysql. If so, this is not right. you should pipe sql file's content to mysql

Comment: If I run that command manually mysql --user=myuser --password=password myDB < myBackupFile.sql it works OK just not via C#

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with python and mysql but what i would do is open the file and read it as if it was a text file strip out any end of line characters and create one sql command that can be executed on the server to restore the data back to the server. I don't know c# very much so i won't be able to write an example. Hope this helps.